# Confirm presence of Slivers / gaps between geometries

Tags: arcmap, shapefile, arcgis-10.7, slivers

Working on ArcGIS 10.7

I have a layer in which, when looking from a certain distance, some aligned white dots appear between two entities (in the image below, the black entity - a road - is formed by 2 parallel geometries, one for each lane):

[image]

When I zoom in, however, the white dots **disappear**. This makes me wonder if the dots are caused by topological errors or just by the software's plotting resolution. I have run "repair geometries" and the points are still there. The layer represented and the data frame both have the same CRS.

[image]

What would be an explanation of this / a way to check what it can be causing it?

Comment: Identify with [geodatabase toplogy rule "Must Not Have Gaps"](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-topology/geodatabase-topology-rules-and-topology-error-fixes.htm#GUID-0A3D7CA2-6CAA-4A44-AA77-1B2F4B24747C). I would then try [Integrate](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/integrate.htm), but backup your data first. Or set the symbol line width to 1.5 to hide the gap.

Comment: You could do a quick visual check by selecting one lane in edit mode and then choosing to edit vertices to see those along the edge.  You can try to remember where the vertices are or you could take a snapshot of them, and then select the other lane and choose edit vertices to see its vertices.  If one lane has vertices the other doesn't then you a very small gap.

Comment: @johns - if that was the case, wouldn't the gap still be visible when I zoom in? it is the fact that the gaps disappear when I zoom in that look weird.

Comment: @Pablo - I think it is most likely just a visual artifact which is why I only suggested a quick check.  I often compare layers by making one white or light gray and the layer below it red and look for differences, and I often see "dotted" red lines in the overview that disappear when I zoom in.

Comment: Thank you @johns - I did it and confirmed that vertices of both entities match and are snapped together, so I will not worry about it for now.